# How to stop a TensorFlow dataset iterator during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I am using `tf.data.Dataset` as mine net input. I typically used this like below:

```
dataset = get_dataset_pipeline(mode='train')
iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
element = iter.get_next()
```

Durning training, i set `dataset.repeat(1)`and every time i used this `dataset`, i will execute `sess.run(iter.initializer)` and `training` mine network, just as follows:

```
for epoch in range(4):
    sess.run(iter.initializer)
    try:
        while True:
            train_step += 1
            input = sess.run(elemeent)
            # some train step here           
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass
    finally:
        pass
```

The question is **how can i stop training early before `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` happed?**. I mean i'm not only want to jump out form train-loop, but also want the `iter` really disabled or deleted form mine system memory. Could anyone can get mine point and give me some advice for that? Thanks a lot~~~